# ASP.NET cannot automatically authenticate user

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have ASP.NET app which can automatically login anyone who is in my database. Any page is auto redirected to login page if user is not authenticated and login page will find user and authenticate him.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       var emp = SQLSelects.SQLSelects.SelectEmployee(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name);
       if (emp != null){
            Session.Add("UserName", emp.Login);
            Session.Add("Access", (int)emp.acessLevel);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(emp.Login, true);

        }
    }
```

Everything worked but now it just throw some kind of Login pop-up formular and request login and password. I don't know why, because I do not know that I was coding anything like that. Any combination of user name and password is not working

In Local Host everything work like it should so I cannot find any problem, nothing. In remote server there is just white screen and login form.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, windows server itself turn off authentication of everything (all our websites fall) and equest update. After update everything is OK.